# Integration with / to

Tags: comparisons

I work in software industry and English is my second language

I have been always using "integration with this software" but today I heard my manager who is native English speaker saying  "integration to this software".

Which one is correct or more accurate ?

Comment: Could your manager have perhaps said "integration **into**"? But without further context, I feel that your use of "with" is more correct. This definition might be helpful: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/integration

Comment: he wrote it down as "integration to" and said it the same way several times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Integration with** is the commonly accepted term in professional usage.

To see this, go to the [Software Engineering Institute webpage](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/index.cfm) at Carnegie Mellon University. Search for "integration-with" and again for "integration-to" (the hyphens seem to make their search engine look for adjacent words as well as hyphenated words).

That said, "integration to" is not completely wrong, since it could convey the idea that a small thing is being integrated into a larger thing at a more remote location, as in a software component being deployed on a mobile phone.

BTW, being a native speaker is not the same as having domain knowledge and a professional vocabulary.  However, if your manager is technically competent and you feel comfortable asking, you might find that their choice of words is conveying an understanding of the system that could be useful for you to know.